# Learning Python on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn Python on Visual Studio Code and I have downloaded Python extensions but when I write a code and press run I see this

```
[Running] swift "c:\Users\w\Desktop\python" 'swift' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.317 seconds
```

I tried to make sure that I have installed all python extensions and I was expecting the code to run

Comment: Make sure you have followed: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what's your question exactly? Do you want to ask *why* you're getting this error, or are you just looking for *some way* to run Python code in VSCode? The latter is off-topic, but there are other resources for that, like Andy linked. See [ask].

Comment: FWIW, it sounds like you have Code Runner configured to run the code as [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_\(programming_language\)) instead of Python. I'm not sure why that would be though. You might want to add a shebang.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your launch.json is fine. (.vscode/launch.json).

If it doesnt exist, create it and put something like this inside it.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope it helps. Also, i've noticed that it was trying to run swift, which is a bit odd, so yeah i think your launch.json just might be messed up. I can't know for sure tho, so post it please

Comment: if you don't set the `cwd` argument that will be his next question

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

##### EDIT:

**Simple solution**: modify your filename to `name.py`.

It looks like your current file name is `python` and has no extension, there are two problems with this, firstly the `python` keyword should not be used as the filename, and secondly the file extension is not added.

Change the name to a normal name. Vscode may recognize your current file as a `swift` file without adding an extension, which is displayed in the lower right corner. So when you run the file with *Code Runner* the `swift` command is used. You can click the displayed `swift` and change the file type to `python`.

[image]

---

The error message says you are running code with the *Code Runner* extension, which is incorrect. Please use the official extension [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) to execute the script.

[image]

It would be helpful to follow [this documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).

Comment: Code Runner can absolutely be configured to run Python code, and I use it all the time, but for OP, as a beginner, yeah it might be better if they avoid it for now.

Comment: Yes, I know that coderunner can also run python very well, but if there are version or package problems, other operations are required, so it is best to avoid using it in the early days and use the official extension python.